# Rails & Devise: Two-step confirmation route error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, registration, confirmation

I'm trying to make a two-step confirmation like heroku using Devise.

My routes:

```
  devise_for :user, :controllers => {:confirmations => "confirmations", :registrations => "registrations" }
    put "confirm_account", :to => "confirmations#confirm_account"
```

Here's my alternate confirmation controller:

```
class ConfirmationsController < Devise::ConfirmationsController
  def show
    @account = User.find_by_confirmation_token(params[:confirmation_token])
    if !@account.present?
      render_with_scope :new
    end
  end

  def confirm_account
    @account = User.find(params[:account][:confirmation_token])
    if @account.update_attributes(params[:account]) and @account.password_match?
      @account = User.confirm_by_token(@account.confirmation_token)
      set_flash_message :notice, :confirmed      
      sign_in_and_redirect("user", @account)
    else
      render :action => "show"
    end
  end

end
```

Here's my `show.html.erb`:

```
<%= form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => confirm_account_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
    <%= f.label :email %>
    <%= @account.email %>
    <%= f.hidden_field :confirmation_token %>
    <%= f.label :password %>
    <%= f.password_field :password %>
    <%= f.label :password_confirmation %>
    <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation %>
    <%= f.submit 'Confirm Account' %>
    <%= link_to 'Home', root_url %>
    <%= render :partial => 'devise/shared/links' %>
<% end %>
```

When I click `confirm` after filling out the password (after clicking confirm in the confirmation email). I'm routed to `/confirm_account.user`  That's pretty weird, right?  What's going on to cause this problem?

**Edit**

`rake routes` returns:

```
        new_user_session GET    /user/sign_in(.:format)                   {:action=>"new", :controller=>"devise/sessions"}
            user_session POST   /user/sign_in(.:format)                   {:action=>"create", :controller=>"devise/sessions"}
    destroy_user_session GET    /user/sign_out(.:format)                  {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"devise/sessions"}
           user_password POST   /user/password(.:format)                  {:action=>"create", :controller=>"devise/passwords"}
       new_user_password GET    /user/password/new(.:format)              {:action=>"new", :controller=>"devise/passwords"}
      edit_user_password GET    /user/password/edit(.:format)             {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"devise/passwords"}
                         PUT    /user/password(.:format)                  {:action=>"update", :controller=>"devise/passwords"}
cancel_user_registration GET    /user/cancel(.:format)                    {:action=>"cancel", :controller=>"registrations"}
       user_registration POST   /user(.:format)                           {:action=>"create", :controller=>"registrations"}
   new_user_registration GET    /user/sign_up(.:format)                   {:action=>"new", :controller=>"registrations"}
  edit_user_registration GET    /user/edit(.:format)                      {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"registrations"}
                         PUT    /user(.:format)                           {:action=>"update", :controller=>"registrations"}
                         DELETE /user(.:format)                           {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"registrations"}
       user_confirmation POST   /user/confirmation(.:format)              {:action=>"create", :controller=>"confirmations"}
   new_user_confirmation GET    /user/confirmation/new(.:format)          {:action=>"new", :controller=>"confirmations"}
                         GET    /user/confirmation(.:format)              {:action=>"show", :controller=>"confirmations"}
             user_unlock POST   /user/unlock(.:format)                    {:action=>"create", :controller=>"devise/unlocks"}
         new_user_unlock GET    /user/unlock/new(.:format)                {:action=>"new", :controller=>"devise/unlocks"}
                         GET    /user/unlock(.:format)                    {:action=>"show", :controller=>"devise/unlocks"}
         confirm_account PUT    /confirm_account(.:format)                {:action=>"confirm_account", :controller=>"confirmations"}
        editreject_admin GET    /admin/:id/editreject(.:format)           {:action=>"editreject", :controller=>"admin"}
            reject_admin GET    /admin/:id/reject(.:format)               {:action=>"reject", :controller=>"admin"}
            accept_admin GET    /admin/:id/accept(.:format)               {:action=>"accept", :controller=>"admin"}
     entries_admin_index GET    /admin/entries(.:format)                  {:action=>"entries", :controller=>"admin"}
 preferences_admin_index GET    /admin/preferences(.:format)              {:action=>"preferences", :controller=>"admin"}
             admin_index GET    /admin(.:format)                          {:action=>"index", :controller=>"admin"}
           about_entries GET    /entries/about(.:format)                  {:action=>"about", :controller=>"entries"}
             all_entries GET    /entries/all(.:format)                    {:action=>"all", :controller=>"entries"}
       myentries_entries GET    /entries/myentries(.:format)              {:action=>"myentries", :controller=>"entries"}
              rate_entry GET    /entries/:id/rate(.:format)               {:action=>"rate", :controller=>"entries"}
            submit_entry PUT    /entries/:id/submit(.:format)             {:action=>"submit", :controller=>"entries"}
          entry_comments POST   /entries/:entry_id/comments(.:format)     {:action=>"create", :controller=>"comments"}
           entry_comment DELETE /entries/:entry_id/comments/:id(.:format) {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"comments"}
                 entries GET    /entries(.:format)                        {:action=>"index", :controller=>"entries"}
                         POST   /entries(.:format)                        {:action=>"create", :controller=>"entries"}
               new_entry GET    /entries/new(.:format)                    {:action=>"new", :controller=>"entries"}
              edit_entry GET    /entries/:id/edit(.:format)               {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"entries"}
                   entry GET    /entries/:id(.:format)                    {:action=>"show", :controller=>"entries"}
                         PUT    /entries/:id(.:format)                    {:action=>"update", :controller=>"entries"}
                         DELETE /entries/:id(.:format)                    {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"entries"}
                                /auth/:service/callback(.:format)         {:controller=>"services", :action=>"create"}
                services GET    /services(.:format)                       {:action=>"index", :controller=>"services"}
                         POST   /services(.:format)                       {:action=>"create", :controller=>"services"}
                    root        /(.:format)                               {:controller=>"entries", :action=>"index"}
                 offline        /offline(.:format)                        {:controller=>"application", :action=>"offline"}
```

**Edit 3**
In changing

```
  devise_for :user, :controllers => {:confirmations => "confirmations", :registrations => "registrations" } do
        match "/confirm_account", :to => "confirmations#confirm_account"
    end
```

I'm receiving :

> You have a nil object when you didn't
>   expect it! You might have expected an
>   instance of Array. The error occurred
>   while evaluating nil.[]

```
{"utf8"=>"âœ“",
 "authenticity_token"=>"dsG/e8Tw2Oi6zEDb07R/L0yDOKFEFlse+IgLbfz3Lo0=",
 "user"=>{"confirmation_token"=>"",
 "password"=>"[FILTERED]",
 "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]"},
 "commit"=>"Confirm Account"}
```

There's definitely a token in the url, though...This is actually going somewhere, though!

Comment: why not just :url => confirm_account_path ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to me like `confirm_account_path` doesn't exist?

If you didn't set up your routes manually, you can go ahead and set that in the `config/routes.rb` file, to `confirmations#confirm_account`.

Or, if you set Devise to use your `ConfirmationsController`, using `new_user_confirmation_path` may work too (and may not). Type `rake routes` in the console to see available routes. They should lead to the `ConfirmationsController` and the `confirm_account` action.

EDIT: Try editing your routes file as follows.

```
devise_for :user, :controllers => {:confirmations => "confirmations", :registrations => "registrations" } do
    match "/confirm_account" => "confirmations#confirm_account"
end
```

I *think* the slash is important before `confirm_account` because it is now inside the `devise_for` block (which is identical to `devise_scope`). Otherwise it may go to `users/confirm_account`.

EDIT2: Use `params[:user][:confirmation_token]`, not `params[:account][:confirmation_token]` in the controller. But currently it looks like the confirmation token is blank.

Comment: You're right, everything seems right. What's the reasoning behind using PUT? I'd try changing the "put" to "match" in the routes file.

Comment: If I change it to match, I get `Could not find devise mapping for path "/confirm_account". Maybe you forgot to wrap your route inside the scope block? For example: devise_scope :user do match "/some/route" => "some_devise_controller" end`

Comment: Did you try that? They mean to put the `match` inside the curly braces following `devise_for`.

Comment: I honestly have no idea what you mean. How would I do that?

Comment: Oops, brain fart. Not curly braces, but a block. Please see updated answer. **crosses fingers**

Comment: @KevinBrown let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1203/discussion-between-josephychoi-and-kevin-brown)

Comment: I continued a bit in chat last night. I'll be available today to continue, if you wish. :)

Comment: I continued our discussion in a new thread because it's kind of a new topic now. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6611436/rails-devise-two-step-confirmation-params-error  I'd appreciate your continued support, if you still have the energy for my ignorance.