# Rails & Devise: Two-step confirmation params error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord, registration, confirmation

This is a continuation of my [woes and drama](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6588865/rails-devise-two-step-confirmation-route-error) ...

Run through:

- I can enter my email to register!
- I can click the confirmation link!
- I'm taken to the correct page to confirm:

  > http://localhost:3000/user/confirmation?confirmation_token=jxOZQnyixE1PvnrptnYO
- Here's the problem...once I submit the form, I get this error:

`ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in ConfirmationsController#confirm_account`

```
{"utf8"=>"âœ“",
 "_method"=>"put",
 "authenticity_token"=>"qUk6EDoR6N+V0h5O/jLKNZtl0hiaN/g9Gd5YdI2QhIU=",
 "user"=>{"confirmation_token"=>"jxOZQnyixE1PvnrptnYO",
 "password"=>"[FILTERED]",
 "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]"},
 "commit"=>"Confirm Account"}
```

The problem is in line 10:

```
class ConfirmationsController < Devise::ConfirmationsController
  def show
    @user = User.find_by_confirmation_token(params[:confirmation_token])
    if !@user.present?
      render_with_scope :new
    end
  end

  def confirm_account
    @user = User.find(params[:user][:confirmation_token])
    if @user.update_attributes(params[:user]) and @user.password_match?
      @user = User.confirm_by_token(@user.confirmation_token)
      set_flash_message :notice, :confirmed      
      sign_in_and_redirect("user", @user)
    else
      render :action => "show"
    end
  end
end
```

Here's my `show.html.erb`

```
<%= form_for(resource, :url => confirm_account_path) do |f| %>
    <%= f.label :email %>
    <%= @user.email %>
    <%= f.hidden_field :confirmation_token %>
    <%= f.label :password %>
    <%= f.password_field :password %>
    <%= f.label :password_confirmation %>
    <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation %>
    <%= f.submit 'Confirm Account' %>
    <%= link_to 'Home', root_url %>
    <%= render :partial => 'devise/shared/links' %>
<% end %>
```

I've been crying about this for a week...I really hope this is a moronic mistake on my part (and at the same time I don't).

I'll be happy to provide you with more information if you need it.  For my convenience, could you describe your answers throughly--I'm a rails newbie!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to be in finding the user with `User.find(params[:user][:confirmation_token])`.

This is because the `find()` method will look for a user by ID. Using a different method to find the user by confirmation token should return the right user. In the show action you already used this method once.

Hopefully this is the last problem!

Comment: I kind of understand.  I need to find a user where confirmation_token => :confirmation_token, or something, right??? Like I said, I'm a newbie.  I would be really happy if you could expand. Is there a another method I could use besides 'find'?

Comment: Yup! I could tell you, but I think you should find it by yourself. Use the same method from the show action, where it says @user = find...

Comment: Oh...my...goodness. I spent so long on this. That's the way it goes when you're learning, I guess. :)  Thanks so much!

Comment: Yay, congrats! For future reference, the find_by_something() method is available for any record using ActiveRecord. http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html